# Есть ли в C# аналог Stream и функционального программирования из Java?

Tags: java, c#, java-stream

Stream API из Java есть в С# под другим именем?

Comment: в  C# есть намного лучше: `LINQ`

Comment: Вообще-то Streams API и было придумано как аналог LINQ в Java.

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.1.php

Comment: Какая наглость! Может забанить его? Во избежание...

Answer (score 5):

LINQ

**Преимущества**

1. Наличие методов расширений в C#
2. Лучше дизайн API

C#

```
var skippedList = vipNames.Skip(3).ToList(); 
friends = friends.OrderBy(c => c).ToArray();
```

Java

```
skippedList = stream(vipNames).substream(3).collect(toList());
friends = stream(friends).sorted().toArray(String[]::new);
```